# Is it possible to append to Postfix default parameter values?

Tags: postfix

I'd like to append to the default Postfix value of `local_recipient_maps`, defined as:

```
% postconf | grep '^local_recipient_maps'
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
```

Based on [the documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#local_recipient_maps) it seemed like I should be able to just reference the default value in the new value, so I did:

```
# postconf 'local_recipient_maps = $local_recipient_maps hash:/var/lib/mailman3/data/postfix_lmtp'
```

but when I run `postconf` again, it gives me a macro error:

```
% postconf | grep '^local_recipient_maps'
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_sender_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_client_restrictions
postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/master.cf: undefined parameter: mua_helo_restrictions
postconf: warning: unreasonable macro call nesting: "local_recipient_maps"
postconf: fatal: macro processing error
```

Obviously this is not a big deal because I can just copy and paste the original default value, but I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong/if this is (supposed to be) possible because it makes for a nice way to separate different parts of parameters into sections with a comment header explaining what they're for (e.g. this one is going into a `# Mailman` section, because obviously only the last map in `local_recipient_maps` is related to Mailman).

If it matters, I am on Postfix 3.4.10-0+deb10u1 (according to `apt policy postfix`) on Debian 10.

Comment: You have to define all those "mua"s somewhere. Like mua_helo_restrictions = /etc/postfix/mua_helo_restrictions and have your actual file there.

Comment: @Overmind yeah, I've actually never noticed those messages before today. I need to look into them but I'm pretty sure they're unrelated.

Answer (score -1):

If you defined all the mua_* parameters in main.cf, they must have something corresponding that actually exists.

Getting to your exact case, you most likely have something like:

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = mua_sender_restrictions, mua_client_restrictions, mua_helo_restrictions
```

but you did not define in your *.cf `smtpd_client_restrictions=mua_client_restrictions`

**You should have something that finally looks like:**

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = mua_sender_restrictions, mua_client_restrictions, mua_helo_restrictions

mua_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject

mua_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject

mua_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
```

Comment: can you explain exactly how this is related to appending to `local_recipient_maps`?

Comment: It's not related at all. It's a totally different problem.

Comment: Can you explain why ? The MUAs seem to be used for local_recipient_maps and they are not defined correctly. The situation seems identical.